# Grunt Watch command

Tags: gruntjs

Trying to set up Grunt with Roots Bootstrap Starter Template - Installation of grunt seemed to go perfectly fine - but when I run 'grunt watch' and go to change my .less files nothing happens in the terminal and grunt doesn't compile my changes. Here is my terminal output after installing > running grunt > and then running 'grunt watch'.

```
Jeffs-MacBook-Air:roots-master jeffsee55$ grunt
Running "clean:dist" (clean) task
Cleaning assets/css/main.min.css...OK
Cleaning assets/js/scripts.min.js...OK

Running "less:dist" (less) task
File assets/css/main.min.css created.

Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
File "assets/js/scripts.min.js" created.

Running "version" task
Versioning assets/css/main.min.css...OK
Versioning assets/js/scripts.min.js...OK
"lib/scripts.php" updated with new CSS/JS versions.

Done, without errors.
Jeffs-MacBook-Air:roots-master jeffsee55$ grunt watch
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

As I said, I then go to make changes to anything in ANY of my .less files which are located in assets/less. Any tips on troubleshooting? Perhaps reinstalling EVERYTHING including node.js?

Comment: may be you should post your grunt file...

Comment: Attach the grunt file. Cannot give the solution without that as above does not give any error though.

Comment: we need your grunt file to help you troubleshoot, it's should be clear your config for watch is invalid so not triggering the change, but the grunt `default` task have a valid one